# Синхронизировать анимацию между разными пользователями

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, canvas

У меня стоит задача сделать анимацию рулетки. Нужно чтобы у каждого пользователя одинаково отображалась анимация, то есть одна и та же картинка на сайте.

В моем случае анимация присутствует в рулетке, какая начинает крутится с рандомной скоростью, потом уже исходя от силы инерции, рулетка останавливается и выясняется номер на каком она остановилась.

2d рулетка, разделенная на 36 частей, каждая часть имеет свой номер.

Каким лучше образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: Обсчёт на стороне сервера. Клиенту отдаёте, например, json, где указано время в которое должно быть показан тот или иной момент\кадр\ что-то ещё. На стороне клиента смотрите, какое время сейчас. И настало ли оно, чтобы показать кадр. Если веря прошло, то пробегаете дальше. Или показываете результат.

Comment: @n.osennij Я даже приблизительно не представляю как покадрово разделить анимацию и отобразить определенный кадр исходя от времени.

Comment: @n.osennij В моем случае анимация присутствует в рулетке, какая начинается крутится с рандомной скоростью, потом уже исходя от силы энерции, рулетка останавливается и выясняется номер на каком она остановилась.

Comment: @n.osennij 2d рулетка, разделенная на 36 частей, каждая часть имеет свой номер.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что полной синхронизации картинки 1 в 1 между разными пользователями достигнуть нельзя. Например, если пользователь перейдет на другую вкладку, то анимация уже начнет запаздывать так как у вкладки понизился приоритет => меньше квантов времени на ее работу.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Та да, согласен. Много факторов говорят о том, что это реализовать будет проблемно. Поэтому как обход, я придумал заглушку. У меня анимация запускается каждое N время. Если пользователь зашел, а анимация уже не началась, он ее просто не увидит.

Comment: А зачем вообще её синхронизировать?

Comment: @Эникейщик Потому же, зачем и синхронизировать любую онлайн игру.

Comment: Я понимаю, зачем нужна синхронизация в танках. Но зачем в рулетке - непонятно. Если у одного игрока рулетка остановится на 2 секунды позже, чем у другого, то чем это грозит? Кстати, там 37 секторов, а не 36.

Comment: @Эникейщик Какие задачи поставлены, такие и выполняю;)

Comment: А, понимаю :) .

Comment: очевидно что отсчеты надо вести на сервере а клиентам лишь отправлять состояние

Answer (score 1):

рандомное значение, и силу инерции - надо сообщить всем игрокам и после запускать анимацию и тогда у всех по идее должна запускаться одинаковая анимация